# Tabulator getData() function Doesn't Return data when added using tab key (tabEndNewRow option)

Tags: tabulator

If you configure a Tabulator table with the option `tabEndNewRow: true,` it looks like the `rowAdded` event passes a row without data in it. I'm new to Tabulator, so I might be doing something wrong - any help would be appreciated!

This JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/splemp/nr76Lh1t/.
Enter a value in Quantity and tab 2 or 3 times to trigger a new row.

- Expected results: console should show row.getData() has some values in it
- Actual results: console shows row.getData() returns an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - `rowAdded` returns a reference to the row that was just added, which would be blank when you tab to a new empty row.